# How to create Domain wise access key and secret key in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two domain. **www.x.com**  and **www.y.com**, now I need to create different access key and secret key for the domain.Now I am new to AWS and I am not getting any solution how to set in AWS  console.

I google it but not find any correct solution.

Kindly suggest some solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying that you need access key and secret key for a domain? Access keys are tight to an IAM identity, user (permanent) or role (temporary), not to a domain.

Comment: Ok, so for the service sns and ses one pair of access key and secret key is fine or i have to create two different pair for both **SES And SNS Service**

Comment: That is fundamentally wrong question. Access key id and secret access key are used for authentication, not authorization.

Comment: Actually my client wants separate access and secret key for two separate domain.Is this right or one access and secret key is works for both domain?

Comment: I know, I am asking very basic question but no one is here who can guide me.